# Set default new folder with custom content type

Tags: content-type

I had a custom content type for new folder in my sharepoint : http://puu.sh/j8kG8/e25153386e.png

How can I bind it to "New Folder" button?

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it worked for me quite well. 
1. Create a new custom folder content type (inherit from folder) 
2. Add that folder to the library. 
3. Remove the default folder from the library (use Sharepoint Manager, or PS
http://get-spscripts.com/2010/11/add-and-remove-site-content-types-from.html
4. Now the custom folder type should be default, even if you create folders from the explorer view via WebDAV (NB but that will not give you option to fill in any metadata if you have associated it with the folder but it will be ok for some migration scenarios).

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

The default "New Folder" button's function can't be changed or customized directly. A workaround would be to replace the "New Folder" button with a custom ribbon button.

A 2010-way to replace the "New Folder" button would'be been this:

```
< CustomAction Id="Ribbon.Documents.New.NewFolder.ReplaceButton"
Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
RegistrationId="101"
RegistrationType="List"
Title="Replace Ribbon Button"
>
< CommandUIExtension >
< CommandUIDefinitions >
< CommandUIDefinition
Location="Ribbon.Documents.New.NewFolder" >
< Button Id="Ribbon.Documents.New.NewFolder.ReplacementButton"
Command="MyNewButtonCommand"
Image16by16="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/img.png" Image16by16Top="-240" Image16by16Left="-80"
Image32by32="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/img2.png" Image32by32Top="-352" Image32by32Left="-448"
ToolTipTitle="Create a New Folder"
ToolTipDescription="Replaced by XML Custom Action"
LabelText="My New Folder"
TemplateAlias="o1" / >
< /CommandUIDefinition >
< /CommandUIDefinitions >
< CommandUIHandlers >
< CommandUIHandler
Command="MyNewButtonCommand"
CommandAction="javascript:alert('New Folder Replaced.');" / >
< /CommandUIHandlers >
< /CommandUIExtension >
< /CustomAction >
```

([Source](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/11/01/replace-ribbon-button-with-your-own-sharepoint-2010/))

There are a plenty of resources documented about this, try with `"ribbon" button replace sharepoint 2013` on your search engine.